# SQL random 4 rows with distinct column

Tags: mysql

I have table representing music tracks with columns id, artist, name, src, sample_start and level.
I want to select random 4 rows but with distinct artists and specified level.
The closest I got was this, but it's not random as max id is selected.

```
'SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE level = :level AND id IN
 (SELECT max(id) FROM tracks GROUP BY artist)
 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4'
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this?

```
SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE LEVEL = :LEVEL AND id IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM tracks ORDER BY RAND()) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4
```

Comment: It doesn't select distinct artists, id's are distinct by default.

Comment: Just remove distinct and check it.

Comment: Also, Provide some data sample for input & output then it's better.